# Getting date of the event from Google Analytics APIs

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to get the date/time of the event from even tracking code of Google analytics? Is there any dimension which will give the event date? I am using Google analytics java api v3. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you combine the some of the [Event Tracking - Dimensions & Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=event_tracking)  with some of the [Time - Dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time)  you should find what you are looking for.